# Create table with > 65.000 rows efficiently from Excel file in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I am currently working on a feature in my project that should fulfill the following function:
 - the user can browse for an excel file (with as much as 65.000 rows)
 - my tool should then somehow (not so important how as long as it's more or    less efficient) populate a datagrid with that data. 
 - the tool should then modify the table in several ways and at last the user  can select several rows that will be stored to a database.

I have already tried:
 - using Interop, but going through all the rows in the Excel file and displaying them in the datagrid alone took more than 10 minutes
 - creating a SSIS package in SQL Server Management Studio, which was much faster (just a few seconds). However, I haven't found a way to use that in my WPF application. Plus I'd need to add at least one column via code-behind (again, I don't know how to do that) which contains a reference ID.

I know my 'question' is very vague, but I really don't know what I should look for. I hope some of you have already done something similar and can tell me how they did it or how they would do it.

Cheers

Comment: Your question is really vague, I would recommend taking a look at the ClosedXML library - https://closedxml.codeplex.com/

Comment: Besides, that the question is vague - why should someone see 65.000 rows AT ONCE? And if you read it with interop - don't do it row by row. You can also query the Excel file with ADO.Net

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way.
I converted the Excel file into cvs, used a StreamReader and read the lines into a DataTable as plain text.
Then I went over that DataTable, created Objects that I then added to an Observable Collection.
It takes less than 3 seconds :)
Thanks for the comments